# Is there any alternative to connect MySQL server to Azure Data Factory for MAC

Tags: mysql, azure, integration, azure-data-factory

I am trying to connect the SQL server to Azure Data Factory for coping the data from server to Blob containers.
SO I am able to create MySQL server on MySQL Workbench but in pipeline setup when I am trying to declare the Source I am unable to connect the server due to unavailability of Integration Runtime file for MAC

So can anyone help me in finding any alternative for Integration Runtime or getting the .dmg file for Integration Runtime

I am new to these technologies so please don't mind if its a very basic question!
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the first part of your question what you try to do with MySQL and SQL Server. However, the integration runtime is available for Windows only.

Answer (score 0):

First question, you said you are trying to connect the SQL server to Azure Data Factory for coping the data from server to Blob containers.

Azure data fata factory has provide the tutorial for us, please reference:

1. [Copy data from an on-premises SQL Server database to Azure Blob
   storage by using the Copy Data tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-hybrid-copy-data-tool).
2. [Copy data from an on-premises SQL Server database to Azure Blob
   storage(UI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-hybrid-copy-portal)
3. [Tutorial: Copy data from an on-premises SQL Server database to Azure
   Blob storage(PowerShell)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-hybrid-copy-powershell)

Second question,  create MySQL server on MySQL Workbench but in pipeline setup when I am trying to declare the Source I am unable to connect the server due to unavailability of Integration Runtime file for MAC.

SQL server and MySQL server are different, I guess your question is copy data from on-premise MySQL server to Azure Blob storage container.

No matter which way to copy data from on-premise source, it all need [Integration Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime). But the limit is:

> 'Currently, we only support running the self-hosted IR on a Windows operating system'.

You can reference [Copy data from MySQL using Azure Data Factory](http://Copy%20data%20from%20MySQL%20using%20Azure%20Data%20Factory) to get more details.

I don't think anyone can help you find the .dmg file for Integration Runtime.

Hope this helps.